# Call fom view to Contoller with a value in CI like requestAction in cakephp

Tags: codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter . Is there any function to call a function from view page to a controllers function with a value just like requestAction in cakephp .

Home Controller:

```
function getSubmenu($menu_id)
 {
    $data['sub_menu_list']=$this->menus->getSUbMenuList($menu_id);
    return $data;
 }
```

index.php (under same controller)

```
from here I want to call getSubmenu($menu_id) function.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the another function in the same class you can do it like this

```
$this->method_name($parameter);
```

in your example is like this:

```
$this->getSubmenu($menu_id);
```

For more informacion, you can read [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html) of CI:

Comment: it shows a error Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Loader::getSubmenu()

Comment: If I understand correct your question, I think my answer is correct. If not, be more specific please, cuz I like to help you. Thanks